# Pyspark dataframe: Summing over a column while grouping over another

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.3

I have a dataframe such as the following

```
In [94]: prova_df.show()


order_item_order_id order_item_subtotal
1                   299.98             
2                   199.99             
2                   250.0              
2                   129.99             
4                   49.98              
4                   299.95             
4                   150.0              
4                   199.92             
5                   299.98             
5                   299.95             
5                   99.96              
5                   299.98
```

What I would like to do is to compute, for each different value of the first column, the sum over the corresponding values of the second column.
I've tried doing this with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
prova_df.groupBy("order_item_order_id").agg(func.sum("order_item_subtotal")).show()
```

Which gives an output

```
SUM('order_item_subtotal)
129.99000549316406       
579.9500122070312        
199.9499969482422        
634.819995880127         
434.91000747680664
```

Which I'm not so sure if it's doing the right thing.
Why isn't it showing also the information from the first column?
Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 15):

> Why isn't it showing also the information from the first column?

Most likely because you're using outdated Spark 1.3.x. If thats the case you have to repeat grouping columns inside `agg` as follows:

```
(df
    .groupBy("order_item_order_id")
    .agg(func.col("order_item_order_id"), func.sum("order_item_subtotal"))
    .show())
```

Answer (score 8):

A similar solution for your problem using **PySpark 2.7.x** would look like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 299.98),
    (2, 199.99),
    (2, 250.0),
    (2, 129.99),
    (4, 49.98),
    (4, 299.95),
    (4, 150.0),
    (4, 199.92),
    (5, 299.98),
    (5, 299.95),
    (5, 99.96),
    (5, 299.98)],
    ['order_item_order_id', 'order_item_subtotal'])

df.groupBy('order_item_order_id').sum('order_item_subtotal').show()
```

Which results in the following output:

```
+-------------------+------------------------+
|order_item_order_id|sum(order_item_subtotal)|
+-------------------+------------------------+
|                  5|       999.8700000000001|
|                  1|                  299.98|
|                  2|                  579.98|
|                  4|                  699.85|
+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use partition in a window function for that:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

df.withColumn("value_field", f.sum("order_item_subtotal") \
  .over(Window.partitionBy("order_item_order_id"))) \
  .show()
```

Comment: what is value_field here?

Comment: Just an arbitrary string that you want the column to be named