# Sum columns of a dataset

Tags: pyspark

I'm working in PySpark and I have a dataset like this :

[image]

I want to create a new df like this with the corresponding sums :

[image]

So I tried this code :

```
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("month_actual_january", "monthjanuary")
    fin=df.groupBy(["column1","column2"]).sum()
```

The problem is that I get the following error :

`Attribute sum(column3) contains an invalid character among  ,;{}()\n\t=. Please use an alias to rename it`

Do you know how to fix this error ? Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark dataframe: Summing over a column while grouping over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961899/pyspark-dataframe-summing-over-a-column-while-grouping-over-another)

Answer (score 0):

Lets try use least squares to pass a wild card alias as follows

```
   df.groupBy(["column1","column2"]).agg(*[sum(x).alias(f"sum_{x}") for x in df.drop("column1","column2").columns]).show()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. It solve the previous problem of  the column names but I have a new error : 

Unsupported operation between types 
+ is not a supported operation for types int and str. 

So I checked my columns types and they are all integers except column1 and column2 but in your code you exclude them so I don't understand why I get this error...

Comment: This is my columns type : 
Column1 (string) Column2 (string) Column3 (integer) Column4 (integer) Column5 (integer)
And I check the columns 3 4 and 5 values I have integers in all cells

Comment: @Nabs335 see if you have imported `sum()` from pyspark sql functions